# What are the differences between these methods to access other classes in Java?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Currently I am getting into Java development, and I am struggling to understand the concept of instances and things of that nature. When I have a variable or method I need to access in another class, currently I do

```
public class Class1 implements Listener {
private final Main main;
private final Class2 class2;

public Class1(Main main, Class2 class2) {
    this.main= main;
    this.class2 = class2;
}
```

I should mention that I am trying to develop a minecraft plugin, so a Listener class must implement Listener. However, when I try to register the events (again, another thing with minecraft,) for a class needing to reference 2 classes, the code gets messy. For example, of a class to get a class that references 2 others, the eventRegister can look like this: (in main class)

```
  pm.registerEvents(new ClassX(this, new ClassY(this, new ClassZ(this))), this);
```

(register events takes a Listener and a main class)

My question asks: what is the difference between this method of getting another class, and simply extending it. It there a difference?

Comment: Which modding API are you using? Listeners are not a part of Minecraft, but a design pattern that various API's use.

Comment: I am using the spigot API @RyanTheLeach

Comment: For your main class, why not `public static Main instance`? Now you can access your main mod instance from anywhere using `Main.instance`. Forge even has an annotation to inject the class instance automatically.

Answer (score 2):

When you extend a class, you're applying Inheritance. You will have access to all `public` methods from the superclass.

When you implement an interface, you're signing a contract where you must implement all non-default methods from that interface.

Comment: I'm wondering the difference between extending, and using the Main main=this.main method (constructor?)

Comment: Extending is when you want to have access to the `public` methods from the super class. You won't need to redeclare them because you inherited it from the super class. When you instantiate a class, you have access to its public methods, but they are not from your class.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass one instance into another instance (via constructor in your case), you are applying [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), which is similar to saying "I will put this specific piece of engine into this specific car". You might want to put a different engine into a different car, so you will pass a different engine as a constructor.

The `implements` is called [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)). The idea behind inheritance is knowing that all classes are *of the same kind*. For example, you might say "all cars can turnLeft() and turnRight()", therefore if anyone wants to create their own car (or in your case - their own plugin), their car also needs to be able to `turnRight()` and `turnLeft()`.

Let's circle back to your question. If you see a piece of code that looks "generic", you might want to extract the generic part into its own class and then inherit that class. For example "all animals can `shout()`" or "all tools can be `use()`-d". However, if you want this duck to know about that duck - you need to have a reference of one duck in the other duck.

However, that does not mean that you need to use constructors. Constructor is for references that the object can not exist without (can not be in valid state). For example `new Duck(new DuckBrain())` makes sense, but `new Duck(new Duck())` does not make sense. For those cases, you might introduce [setters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) (search for Java example in the link). Setters are methods which change what the object contains.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the class an instance of every individual thing you need, just give it the object which stores them. In your case, it is probably your plugin's main class.

```
class ClassA implements Listener {

    private final MyPlugin plugin;

    public ClassA(MyPlugin plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
}
```

Just make sure everything in `MyPlugin` are accessable from `ClassA` using access modifiers or getters.

Answer (score 0):

What you have been doing is completely normal, and is encouraged. Overuse of inheritance where it's not explicitly designed for can lead to bad code.

You are also passing what each class needs via constructors, this is also good practice known as Dependency Injection, and helps to allow better testing, and the writing of unit tests.

With advanced projects, it's common to use Dependency Injection frameworks in order to manage your dependencies being passed into many classes, but it shouldn't be necessary for a small plugin.

Depending on how reusable those classes are, you may wish to make some interfaces for them.

If constructing the classes using dependency injection becomes a chore, you can look into several patterns to assist.

Factory and Builder patterns are used extensively through industry, depending on how often, how complex, and how varied the objects being constructed get.

Complex objects, created often lend themselves well to the [Factory pattern](http://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/abstract-factory/).

Simple objects, with high variability, lend themselves well to the [builder pattern](http://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/builder/).

If passing everything via the constructor becomes difficult, you can always initialize the objects after construction, but this has a maintenance cost, as you then need to make sure that the objects are initialized correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Why your class1 need reference to class2?? is it an object or something in OO programming this mean your code will become very couple which is a bad design you should use other design pattern to decouple you code i.e. Class1 should not depend on Class2.

Back to your question what is the difference of passing the object via the constructor vs extending it??.

When you extend a class you can override some of the method in the mother class i.e. `Dog extends Animal` or you can even call the method in your super class (the Animal class via `super.method()`).

When you pass a class in this case an object via the constructor you can use the object in the you pass in via the constructor.

The best way to make your code less messy I recommend the Listener Pattern (the pub sub) there are existing library such as https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus where you can create an event for example can an event when a Player dies you create another class that is subscribe to that event and when an event happen it will notified all the subscriber to trigger a function. Now you do not need to couple all the classes together.

Comment: Classes having dependencies is absolutely normal. The size of a typical plugin project is small enough that coupling is rarely an issue.